# Let W be a linear subspace. Can venn diagram/ euler diagrams be used to prove that (W⊥)⊥＝W?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, vector-spaces, orthogonality

Here is my method.
First I draw something (A) with a closed shape that represents the n-dimensional vector space **R**. W is a subspace of **R**, so I can draw something (B) with a closed shape inside A that represents W. From the definition of orthogonal complement　W⊥ is (A-B)⋃Z. Z is  the region representing the zero vector.  Again from the definition of orthogonal complement　(W⊥)⊥is (A-(A-B))⋃Z=B⋃Z.Of course Z is part of B so B⋃Z=B. Therefore (W⊥)⊥＝W.
If this method is correct I can use it prove that (W1+W2)⊥=W1⊥⋂W2⊥,(W1⋂W2)⊥=W1⊥+W2⊥ and so on.

However, is it proper to use such euler diagrams here? I have little to no knowledge of euler diagrams. In fact I do not have any knowledge of the proofs of theorems about such diagrams. Does (W⊥)⊥＝W follow from such theorems or some of these theorems follow from the fact that (W⊥)⊥＝W?
I get the feeling that to prove (W⊥)⊥＝W I have used a consequence of (W⊥)⊥＝W.

Comment: A-B represents the set of all vectors that are not part of B.  If a vector is not part of B then it must be perpendicular to B.

Comment: In the solution 2-dimensional forms does not  need to represent part of the plane. They represent only the above-mentioned sets of vectors. Please, do not confuse the two ideas.